# symfony fos_user_bundle will not work.

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am getting into symfony and made a small project with several empty provider. 
I used this tutorial to install FOS_USERBUNDLE.

All my routes are convigured as annotations in the controllers

And thats my only one access_control:

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/invoices/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

There are actually no users or other data saved. 
I would expect that the route www.myapp.com/invoices does not work. But it works.

What could it be?

regards
n00n

Comment: Have you got 'firewalls' section set in your 'security.yml'?

Comment: Yes, got that section, ...

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you've added extra `/`
Try this

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/invoices, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now, `www.myapp.com/invoices` should be accessible.

Remember no trailing `/` in `access_control` for the `path`

Comment: Works now, but.... if I logon with the created and activated user, it throws  The server returned a "403 Forbidden". The role I would like to use was "- { path: ^/invoices, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED}"

Comment: oh, ok, user role has to be added to the user. Do I have to add IS_AUTHENTICATED to each user manually or is there any role added automatically?